# Need help automatically starting wireless - can start from command line

Tags: wireless, hp, broadcom

Installed 14.04 on an HP zv6000, and if I run:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb
sudo modprobe b43
```

then wireless works perfectly, but I have to run it each time from a terminal.

I'm a novice at Ubuntu - which file can I add these commands to so that wireless starts up when the computer first turns on from power off, and also from sleep mode?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything but add the firmware (package linux-firmware-nonfree) to have the b43 driver work.  No additions to /etc/modules, no uncommenting blacklisted items.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **/etc/modules** file.  Add b43 the following:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

b43
```

You may have to put comment out the blacklisted bcm43xx in your **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** file.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste for accuracy one line at a time:

```
sudo su 
echo b43 >> /etc/modules 
exit
```

now it should start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you have a file that blacklists *b43*:

```
ls /etc/modprobe.d
```

Is there a file there called blacklist-bcm43.conf? If so, this file blacklists *b43* and prevents it from loading on boot as expected. Please remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Now *b43* should load correctly on boot.